# getting the image source of an sibling element

Tags: jquery

I want to alert the image source of an element that is close to it when i clicked an anchor.

here is the structure:

```
<div class = 'image_div'>
   <img src = "pics/smiley.jpg" class = "smiley_pic">
   <a class = 'click_me'>click me</a>
</div>
```

here is my jquery:

```
$('.click_me').click(function(){
 alert($(this).closest('img').siblings('img.smiley_pic').attr('src'));
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('a').click(function(){
   alert($(this).prevAll('img').first().attr("src"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = 'image_div'>
   <img src = "pics/smiley.jpg" class = "smiley_pic">
   <a class = 'click_me'>click me</a>
</div>
```

You could also use `.prev()` but that would work only if it is exactly previous, while my answer will get the closest `<img>`

Comment: It works, but what is the difference between this code, and the code of Milind Anantwar?

Answer (score 1):

You have incorrect selector to target sibling img element. use:

```
$('.click_me').click(function(){
  alert($(this).prev().attr('src'));
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8ng5ezn7/)**